# How to building a rpm from multiple projects

Tags: linux, makefile, rpmbuild

I know how to build rpm for its own project, however I am not sure what is the proper way to build a rpm that depend on multiple projects to be build first. For example, say I have project A, B, C, D, and FINAL.

- B needs A
- C needs A
- D needs B and C
- FINAL needs D

So if i am to make rpm for `FINAL`, what would be the proper way to trigger the other projects to build?

- Make a shell script that trigger the calls and call it under `%build`?
- In the Makefile of `FINAL`

Comment: What's the nature of A, B, C , and D? If they are stand-alone libraries or run-time dependencies, I would make a separate RPM for each. If they are completely a part of this build, doesn't the upstream Makefile already orchestrate these things for you?

Comment: They are standalone, the `FINAL` just need the generated library from the others.

Answer (score 1):

Your specfile should say it `Requires` "D" and `BuildRequires` "D-devel" or something similar. The "D" RPM(s) should handle the A/B/C requirements. You shouldn't be building unrelated RPMs at the same time.